# Access a variable instantiated within a Python exec() command - works but throws NameError exception

Tags: python, scope, exec

I'm trying to import and run a module named dynamically at run time (Python 3.4 / Django 1.7).

I tried:

```
exec('ds_id = kim_processors.%s.process(%s)' % (function.python_module, model_id))
cursor.execute("""sql""", (ds_id, ))
```

I get the NameError exception "Exception Value: name 'ds_id' is not defined", yet again, I can see ds_id in the local vars listing:

```
ds_id   14
```

I also tried:

```
exec('import kim_processors.%s as processor_module' % function.python_module)
ds_id = processor_module.process(model_id)
```

Django reports the NameError exception "Exception Value: name 'processor_module' is not defined". But I can see processor_module listed in localvars, set to the module:

```
processor_module <module 'kim_processors.someprocessing' from 'C:\\_dev\\kimetrica\\KimSim\\KimSimPrototype\\kimsim_modelbuilder\\kim_processors\\someprocessing.py'>
```

Don't think it is necessary, but I've also tried passing global() and local() to exec:

```
exec('import kim_processors.%s as processor_module' % function.python_module, globals(), locals())
exec('ds_id = processor_module.process(%s)' % (model_id), globals(), locals())
dataset_id_parameter = (ds_id, )
```

And declaring ds_id as global before those statements (also not great but in desperation):

```
global ds_id
...
```

Same NameError. Any idea how I can access that module or variable, which is and isn't there?

Comment: Is this in a function?

Comment: The definition of `process(..)` within the module is `def process(model_id): ...`. The value in `ds_id` listed in local vars is correct. (I'm new to Python but assume that is indeed unambiguously a function.)

Comment: That is indeed a function. There are far better ways to dynamically execute code, however. You can use `importlib` to import modules dynamically, for example.

Comment: Not yet fully sure, but looks like this is working `processor_module = importlib.import_module('kim_processors.%s' % function.python_module)` - huge thanks