# Capture Return Value from exec

Tags: python

**`yaml` file:**

```
$ cat ec2_attr.yml

treeroot:
    branch1:
        name: Node 1
        snap: |
          def foo():

              from boto3.session import Session
              import pprint

              session = Session(region_name='us-east-1')
              client = session.client('rds')

              resp = client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots(
                  SnapshotType='manual',
              )

              filtered = [x for x in resp['DBClusterSnapshots'] if x[
                  'DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier'].startswith('xxxxx')]
              latest = max(filtered, key=lambda x: x['SnapshotCreateTime'])
              print(latest['DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier'])

          foo()        
    branch2:
        name: Node 2
```

**Code:**

```
import yaml
import pprint

with open('./ec2_attr.yml') as fh:
    try:
        yaml_dict = yaml.load(fh)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        exec("a = yaml_dict['treeroot']['branch1']['snap']")
        print('The Value is: %s' % (a))
```

**Actual Output:**

```
The Value is: def foo():

    from boto3.session import Session
    import pprint

    session = Session(region_name='us-east-1')
    client = session.client('rds')

    resp = client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots(
        SnapshotType='manual',
    )

    filtered = [x for x in resp['DBClusterSnapshots'] if x[
        'DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier'].startswith('xxxxx')]
    latest = max(filtered, key=lambda x: x['SnapshotCreateTime'])
    print(latest['DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier'])

foo()
```

**Expected output:**

```
xxxxx-xxxx-14501111111-xxxxxcluster-2gwe6jrnev8a-2017-04-09
```

If I use `exec` as `exec(yaml_dict['treeroot']['branch1']['snap'])`, Then it does print the value that I want, but I cannot capture that value into a variable. I understand that `exec` return value is `None`. However, I am trying to do something exactly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23917810/1251660, and it is not working in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exec` like this:

```
import yaml
import pprint

with open('./a.yaml') as fh:
    try:
        yaml_dict = yaml.load(fh)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    else:
      a = {}
      exec(yaml_dict['treeroot']['branch1']['snap'], {}, a)
      print('The Value is: %s' % (a['foo']()))
```

And change your YAML to this:

```
treeroot:
  branch1:
      name: Node 1
      snap: |
        def foo():
            return("test")

  branch2:
      name: Node 2
```

Actually, You can use `exec(str, globals, locals`)

- [globals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals)
- [locals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals)

The built-in functions `globals()` and `locals()` return the current global and local dictionary, respectively, which may be useful to pass around for use as the second and third argument to `exec()`.

Also, You can read [The exec Statement and A Python Mystery](https://late.am/post/2012/04/30/the-exec-statement-and-a-python-mystery.html) and [locals and globals](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html)

Comment: Perfect. This is what I needed. Could you explain what's going on here. I am not able to interpret https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec correctly.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I tried to explain a little more  :)