# How to get the returned value of a function, called by exec() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-exec

I have a function called 'somefunc' :

```
def somefunc():
    return "ok"
```

And i wanted to run it with exec() like :

```
exec("somefunc()")
```

That works great. But the problem is, i can't get the returned value "ok".
I've tried to do this:

```
a = exec("somefunc()")
print (a)
```

But i've  got nothing. 
how can i get the returned value?

Comment: exec("a = somefunc()") https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917776/how-do-i-get-the-return-value-when-using-python-exec-on-the-code-object-of-a-fun

Comment: You could create a dictionary of functions keyed by their names if you need to dynamically invoke functions by a string variable. `exec` solutions are seldom optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use exactly the `exec()` function, the answer by @Leo Arad is okay.

But I think you misunderstood `exec()` and `eval()` functions. If so, then:

```
a = exec("somefunc()")
print (a)
```

It'd work when you'd use `eval()`:

```
a = eval("somefunc()")
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the function output straight to `a`

```
def somefunc():
    return "ok"

exec("a = somefunc()")
print(a)
```

Output

```
ok
```

`exec()` is executing the statement that you provide it as text so in this case, the exec will store the return value the `a` variable.