# Using compile() with an expression with a function inside of it

Tags: python, compilation, expression, eval

Let's say I have something like this:

```
expr="
def something():
     return True
something()"

somevar=compile(expr, "","eval")
```

This throws a syntax error on "def". I've also tried wrapping the compile() with an eval(), no use. I basically want the result of the function call. Is this possible with eval or compile? Is there any library that would achieve this? I want somevar to be False.
Thanks in advance

Comment: it may need `exec` instead of `eval`

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile):

> The mode argument specifies what kind of code must be compiled; **it can be 'exec' if source consists of a sequence of statements**, 'eval' if it consists of a single expression, or 'single' if it consists of a single interactive statement

So there's a couple of things here:

1. You should use [multi-line strings](https://www.techbeamers.com/python-multiline-string/) in Python (three `"""`)
2. You shouldn't use `"eval"` but `"exec"`
3. The returned object is not executed. You have to explicitly call it once created.

With all that in mind:

```
expr = """
def something():
    print('hi')
    return "done"

something()
"""

somevar = compile(expr, "", "exec")
exec(somevar)
```

This does print `"hi"`. However, that code itself doesn't return anything. You run the function `something()` which yes: returns `"done"` but after running `something()`? Where would you *return the return*?

One option, as explained in [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23917776/289011) would be assigning the return value to what would become a sort of "global" variable:

```
expr = """
def something():
    return "done"

retval = something()
"""

somevar = compile(expr, "", "exec")
exec(somevar)
print(retval)
```

I can't help but saying that this sort of convoluted coding, that runs code stored in strings is probably a bad idea. It's insecure, hard to track, debug, refactor... So if this is going to be used for something besides learning purposes... Well... I would invite you to try and think if there's another way of achieving what you want.