# Why does `exec(f"module.{function}")` return NoneType instead of executing the function?

Tags: python

I'm making a module for my python program that has functions built in that return dictionaries.
Here's one of them:

```py
def Number(id:str, startVal=0, roundMode=1):
        self = {}

        self["id"] = id
        self["startVal"] = startVal
        self["roundMode"] = roundMode

        self["Set"] = str(f"{self['id']}i0")
        self["Get"] = str(f"{self['id']}i1")
        self["Add"] = str(f"{self['id']}i2")

        self["Out"] = str(f"{self['id']}o0")

        return self
```

If I set a variable like this: `health = flscript.Number("hp", 100)`, it returns the correct dictionary.

However, how I'm handling input, `Number("hp", 100)` is stored in a string, so I need to use `exec()`

Using `exec(f"flscript.{value}")`, with value being `Number("hp", 100)`, this is the same as `exec("flscript.Number("hp", 100)")`. For some reason, that works perfectly. But the fstring returns NoneType.

I've tried searching for answers, so sorry if I missed some and this is a repeat question.

I can't do much other than using `exec(f"module.{function}")`, since the function is stored in a string.

As I said above, when using `exec("module.function()")`, it works. But using `exec(f"module.{function}")` (`function` being `"function()"`)

Is there a problem somewhere? Does `exec()` not accept fstrings?

Comment: `However, how I'm handling input, Number("hp", 100) is stored in a string, so I need to use exec()` I think you'll find that you never *need* to use `exec`. If you think you do, then maybe you need to rework your design a bit.

Comment: Do you have a `__str__()` method that returns that string for a `Number` instance? What do you see if you do `print(f"flscript.{value}")`?

Comment: `exec()` does not return a value

Comment: `exec("flscript.Number("hp", 100)")` is a syntax error, but it shouldn't return anything besides `None`. Can you show an example of that?

Comment: @Barmar doing that returns `flscript.Number("hp",100)` in the console.

Comment: @RandomDavis how can I get a value from a function stored in a string without `exec()`?

Comment: Don't store it in a string in the first place. There are almost always better alternatives, unless you're getting it from user input.

Comment: @tdelaney sorry, I was typing that out by hand and didn't notice the quotes in quotes, it would really be `exec("flscript.Number('hp', 100)")`. This returns None.

Comment: @Barmar I'm getting it from user input.

Comment: `exec` always returns `None`. You could do `exec(f"health = flscript.{value}")` and the result would be in `health` in your global namespace.

Comment: I just found this post: [Return Value from exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917776/how-do-i-get-the-return-value-when-using-python-exec-on-the-code-object-of-a-fun)
This worked. Thanks @JonSG for pointing out that exec() doesn't return anything.

Comment: You might want to try `print(eval("Number(\"hp\", 100)"))` as @Barmar observes it does return a value. Deleting my answer as their observation makes my answer moot.

Comment: I hope they don't type something that ends with `or os.system('rm *')`

Comment: Why would you need to delete it? It was an answer, and it was the right answer.
?

Comment: @Barmar don't worry lol, the exec is "hardcoded" to only use functions held in the flscript.py, because it's always `exec(f"flscript.{function}")`, so things like that shouldn't go through, and would probably just return an error.
Edit: Oh, I think I get what you mean. if they type `function() os.system...` it might go through.

Comment: What if `function` is `'Number("hp", 100) or os.system(\'rm *\')'`

Comment: @Barmar How could I prevent something like that? I don't have os imported, so I don't think it would work anyway, but using semi-colons, they can probably import it, then run it

Comment: If you use `eval()`, it only executes expressions, not statements, so it can't have semicolon.

Comment: you don't need to `import os`, Here I'll do it for you :-P `eval("__import__('os').listdir('.')")` and thus why `eval()`, `exec()`, `compile()` are a tad dangerous.

Comment: The key difference is that `exec` treats the function call as an expression statement (which, like any other statement, has no value) rather than an expression (which by definition has a value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `exec()` (implicitly or explicitly) returns `None` as a value. Thus when you `print(exec(....))` it will always print `"None"`.

If you want to make this kind of work (and likely you want to refactor the code to a different solution) you might do:

```py
def Number(id, startVal=0, roundMode=1):
    self = {}
    self["id"] = id
    self["startVal"] = startVal
    self["roundMode"] = roundMode
    self["Set"] = str(f"{self['id']}i0")
    self["Get"] = str(f"{self['id']}i1")
    self["Add"] = str(f"{self['id']}i2")
    self["Out"] = str(f"{self['id']}o0")
    return self

value = "Number(\"hp\", 100)"
exec(f"foo = {value}")
print(foo)
```

As @Barmar observes, you can drop in `eval()` with your current implementation

```py
print(eval("Number(\"hp\", 100)"))
```

or the f-string equivalent works.

Comment: Or use `eval()` instead of `exec()`

Answer (score 1):

`Number("hp", 10)`, to be treated as executable Python code, is not a safe input. Better would be to require something like a JSON object

```
{ "function": "Number",
  "args": ["hp", 10]
}
```

which your program can parse and use to construct an appropriate function call. For example:

```
import json

functions = {"Number": Number, ...}

x = ... # The input

request = json.loads(x)

fname = requests["function"]
fargs = requests["args"]

result = functions[fname](*fargs)
```